Dfs in assembly function
I tried to do this function DFS recursively in assembly and I keep recieving "Segmentation fault" and I don't know from where.
neighbours_t expand(uint32_t node);
void dfs(uint32_t node, neighbours_t *(*expand)(uint32_t node));
%include "../include/io.mac"

; The `expand` function returns an address to the following type of data
; structure.
struc neighbours_t
    .num_neighs resd 1  ; The number of neighbours returned.
    .neighs resd 1      ; Address of the vector containing the `num_neighs` neighbours.
                        ; A neighbour is represented by an unsigned int (dword).
endstruc

section .bss
; Vector for keeping track of visited nodes.
visited resd 10000
global visited

section .data
; Format string for printf.
    fmt_str db "%u", 10, 0

section .text
global dfs
extern printf

; Define the structure for neighbours
struc neighbours_t
    .num_neighs resd 1
    .neighs resd 1
endstruc

; Function to perform depth-first search
; Input: 
;   node -> uint32_t node id
;   expand -> pointer to function expand(uint32_t node) returning neighbours_t*
dfs:
    
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    push edx
    push esi
    push edi
    ; Arguments
    mov eax, [ebp+8]            ; node
    mov ebx, [ebp+12]           ; expand function pointer

    ; Mark the node as visited
    mov edx, eax
    mov ecx, visited
    mov byte [ecx + edx * 4], 1
      ; Mark node as visited

    ; Print the visited node
    push eax
    push fmt_str
    call printf
    add esp, 8

    ; Get neighbours
    push eax                    ; Save current node
    call ebx                    ; Call expand function
    pop eax                     ; Restore current node

    ; Iterate over neighbours
    mov esi, eax                ; neighbours_t* to esi
    mov ecx, [esi + neighbours_t.num_neighs]  ; Number of neighbours
    mov edi, [esi + neighbours_t.neighs]      ; Address of neighbours array
    xor eax, eax                ; Loop counter

dfs_loop:
    cmp eax, ecx               ; Check if all neighbours visited
    jge dfs_end

    ; Get neighbour
    mov edx, [edi + eax*4]

    ; Check if neighbour is visited
    mov ebx, visited
    cmp byte [ebx + edx * 4], 0  ; Check if not visited
    jne dfs_next_neighbour     ; If visited, skip

    ; Recursively call dfs for unvisited neighbour
    push edx
    push ebx
    call dfs
    pop ebx
    pop edx

dfs_next_neighbour:
    inc eax                    ; Increment loop counter
    jmp dfs_loop
    

dfs_end:
    pop edx
    pop esi 
    pop edi
    leave
    ret


I tried to do this function DFS recursively in assembly and I keep recieving "Segmentation fault" and I don't know from where.

A debugger will at least answer the "from where" question for you...

Assuming this is using Linux / SysV calling conventions, the call to printf clobbers eax, ecx, edx, so you will have to save those values somewhere if you want to use them after the call.  The same is true of the recursive call to dfs (which, conversely, does not need to save and restore edx).

@Alexandra Dinu. Why six "push" at the entry of DFS without their counterpart of "pop"?
